# signout from firebase using python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

Iam using django webapp.I signed in with

```
import pyrebase

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
authe = firebase.auth()
user = authe.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email,password)
```

How can I signout in similar way.

Comment: do you mean, you want to close the connection to firebase auth? this might help - `firebase.database().goOffline()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [signOut()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut) function provided by the firebase.auth interface and as the documentation states:

> Signs out the current user.

So in your example:

```
authe.signOut()
```

Comment: `pyrebase` auth has not `signOut()` method

Answer (score 0):

The best way to to logout is to use django session, with the help of below function you can destroy token id on logout:

```
def logout(request):
    try:
        del request.session['token_id']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return HttpResponse("You're logged out.")
```

For complete details, refer to the django session documentation at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

This should work....

```py
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)
auth = firebase.auth()
```

You should use firebase-admin, avoid work arounds like this.

```py
auth.current_user = None
```